# Object Comparison with XCTAssert in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xctest

I have a class:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

In my test, I initialize two instances of the same class, and then compare them:

```
func testSomething() {
    let x = Person("A")
    let y = Person("A")

    XCTAssert(x == y)
}
```

I can't get the test to pass. I tried `===`, `XCTAssertEqual`, `XCTAssertTrue` - but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to test 2 objects using == operator you need to implement `Equatable` protocol for your `Person` class, for instance:

```
func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

And since you inherit from `NSObject` which already implements it, you only need to implement the function without the need to add `Equatable` to `Person` class (which actually wouldn't compile because it already stated in `NSObject` declaration)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement the `Equatable` protocol, you can just check for `name` String equality like this:

```
XCTAssert(x.name == y.name)
```